# No such file or directory on bash assignment

Tags: bash, variables, sed, while-loop, variable-assignment

I'm trying to write an script that saves each line from "test" file in a variable line1, line2, and so on..

```
x=$(cat test | wc -l)   #here i have how many lines
i="1"

while [ "$i" -lt "$x" ]
do
line$i=$(sed '$iq;d' test)   #i try to get the number $i line one by one
i=$[$i+1]                              
done
```

Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a file named `test` in a directory you run this from?

Comment: yes, when i type nano test:

2015-01-29/
2015-01-30/
2015-01-31/
2015-02-01/
2015-02-02/
2015-02-03/
2015-02-04/
2015-02-05/
2015-02-06/

Comment: `line$1` is strange. Try to rename this variable.

Comment: I can help you: `mapfile -t lines < test`. You'll have a beautiful array `lines` the fields of which contain the lines of your file. Print the third line: `printf '%s\n' "${lines[2]}"` (yes, assignment starts with field 0, but this can be changed with the `-O` option).

Comment: The `$[$i+1]` notation is obsolescent; use `$(($i+1))` instead.

Comment: unrelated to the question body, but related to the question title: check that the variable assigned to is a valid variable name (e.g. does not contains hyphens). though obvious, it can be difficult to look past your intent or context to see such errors and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

To read each line of the file `test` into an array called `lines`, use:

```
mapfile -t lines <test
```

#### Example

Consider this file:

```
$ cat test
dogs and cats
lions and tigers
bears
```

Execute this statement:

```
$ mapfile -t lines <test
```

We can now see the value of `lines` using `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p lines
declare -a lines2='([0]="dogs and cats" [1]="lions and tigers" [2]="bears")'
```

Each line of file `test` is now an element of array `lines` and we can access them by number:

```
$ echo "${lines[0]}"
dogs and cats
```

Comment: Haha now you'll get my `+1` `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take advantage of [available tooling](http://www.shellcheck.net) to see what's wrong:

```
$ shellcheck linereader
In linereader line 1:
x=$(cat test | wc -l)   #here i have how many lines
^-- SC2148: Shebang (#!) missing. Assuming Bash.
        ^-- SC2002: Useless cat. Consider 'cmd < file | ..' or 'cmd file | ..' instead.


In linereader line 6:
line$i=$(sed '$iq;d' test)   #i try to get the number $i line one by one
^-- SC1067: For indirection, use (associative) arrays or 'read "var$n" <<< "value"'
^-- SC2034: line appears unused. Verify it or export it.
             ^-- SC2016: Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.


In linereader line 7:
i=$[$i+1]
  ^-- SC2007: Use $((..)) instead of deprecated $[..]
```

That's a good start:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 1. Shebang added
# 2. Redirection for reading files as suggested (stylistic)
x=$(wc -l < test)   #here i have how many lines
i="1"

while [ "$i" -lt "$x" ]
do
  # 3. Using arrays as suggested
  # 4. Using double quotes for sed as suggested
  # Additionally, use ${i} so we reference $i and not $iq
  line[$i]=$(sed "${i}q;d" test)   #i try to get the number $i line one by one

  # 5. Use $((..)) as suggested (stylistic)  
  i=$((i+1))
done

# Print a line to show that it works:
echo "Line #2 is ${line[2]}"
```

And now let's try:

```
$ cat test
foo
bar
baz
$ ./linereader
Line #2 is bar
```

We could also have done this more easily (and in O(n) time) with `mapfile`:

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile line < test
echo "Line #2 (zero-based index 1) is: ${line[1]}"
```

Comment: `mapfile` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

`lines$i` should be `lines[$i]` (or google eval) but chances are you're going about this completely wrong and you should be writing it in awk, e.g.:

```
awk '{lines[NR] = $0} END{print NR; for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) print i, lines[i]}' test
```